# Add rule to mod_security via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have `ModSecurity` enabled on our Apache server, and due to that, we aren't able to make any post request which has links in its payload.

How to configure `ModSecurity` using `.htaccess` in order to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable specific ModSecurity rules, but you can disable it for a specific URL if you really want to (I'm sure it's enabled for a reason and you know what you're doing by switching it off.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/specificURL/#">
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </If>
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** This only works for specifically compiled versions (`--enable-htaccess-config`), otherwise you can't do this via .htaccess

Comment: Then how to know what's wrong with my request script? It's a simple form that work fine if my payload don't have links!

Comment: Try the above, disabling it for your specific request URL and see if that works.

Comment: Do you have access to modify the ModSec rules directly?

Comment: No, but I can request to have an access for it